# Match on field in array only matches when the value is in the first row of the array

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch

I have an index with documents with an array of objects in it called products. Products has a field called feed_id, which I mapped as `products.feed_id` (Text) .

But when I do a match query I just find the documents where the matched feed_id is in the first row of the array. Do I need to map products as nested (I tried that, but It's not working yet, do I need to map the field IN the array as well?)

I have added mapping / query and an example document that is not found. *(Other docs are found if the feed_id is one row 1 of the array)*

**Mapping**

```
{
"products-nl" : {
  "aliases" : { },
  "mappings" : {
    "product" : {
      "dynamic" : "false",
      "properties" : {
        "brand" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "brand_keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "description_short" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "eancode" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "full_title" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "price" : {
          "type" : "float"
        },
        "products" : {
          "properties" : {
            "category_string" : {
              "type" : "text"
            },
            "feed_id" : {
              "type" : "integer"
            },
            "full_shop_title" : {
              "type" : "text"
            },
            "shop_title" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "shop_title_search" : {
              "type" : "text"
            },
            "title" : {
              "type" : "text"
            }
          }
        },
        "providers" : {
          "type" : "nested"
        },
        "shop_amount" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "shop_title_search" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "title" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "total_price" : {
          "type" : "float"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings" : {
    "index" : {
      "creation_date" : "1547042901221",
      "number_of_shards" : "5",
      "number_of_replicas" : "0",
      "uuid" : "OUXvA4kiTJCs1L30ZoYv1w",
      "version" : {
        "created" : "6050499"
      },
      "provided_name" : "products-nl"
    }
  }
}
```

}

**Query**

```
GET products-nl/_search
  {
    "size": 3000,
    "query": {
      "match": {
        "products.feed_id": 15621
      }
    }
  }
```

**Document** (It should be found i'd say because feed_id is in there, but on *row 3* of products).

```
{
"_source": {
  "title": "Disney Frozen 18 Inch 28 cm Meisjes Terugtraprem Mintgroen",
  "products": {
    "0": {
      "title": "Disney Frozen 18 Inch 28 cm Meisjes Terugtraprem Mintgroen",
      "feed_id": "53"
    },
    "2": {
      "title": "Disney Frozen 18 Inch 28 cm Meisjes Terugtraprem Mintgroen",
      "feed_id": "3564"
    },
    "3": {
      "title": "Kinderfiets 18 Inch Meisjes Disney Frozen 51861",
      "feed_id": "15621"
    },
    "4": {
      "title": "Disney Frozen meisjesfiets  18 inch",
      "feed_id": "3251"
    },
    "5": {
      "title": "Disney Frozen 18 Inch Meisjesfiets",
      "feed_id": "6192"
    },
    "6": {
      "title": "Disney Frozen 18 inch meisjesfiets 95 afgemonteerd",
      "feed_id": "460"
    },
    "7": {
      "title": "Disney Frozen 18 inch meisjesfiets",
      "feed_id": "15882"
    },
    "8": {
      "title": "Disney Frozen 95 Meisjes 2018 18inch Blauw",
      "feed_id": "180"
    },
    "9": {
      "title": "Disney Frozen 18 inch meisjesfiets 95 afgemonteerd",
      "feed_id": "399"
    }
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is that (1) you have disabled dynamic mapping and (2) the structure of your `products` items doesn't match the defined mapping. Therefore, the fields are not indexed (i.e., not searchable) even though they appear in the `_source` field ([see documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/dynamic.html)).

Let me be more precise. The mapping of `products` items would match something like this:

```
"products": [
  {
    "title": "Disney Frozen 18 Inch 28 cm Meisjes Terugtraprem Mintgroen",
    "feed_id": "53"
  },
  ...
  {
    "title": "Kinderfiets 18 Inch Meisjes Disney Frozen 51861",
    "feed_id": "15621"
  },
  ...
]
```

Instead, you have this:

```
"products": {
  "0": {
    "title": "Disney Frozen 18 Inch 28 cm Meisjes Terugtraprem Mintgroen",
    "feed_id": "53"
  },
  ...
  "3": {
    "title": "Kinderfiets 18 Inch Meisjes Disney Frozen 51861",
    "feed_id": "15621"
  },
  ...
}
```

, which is a very different mapping. Because these items don't match the mapping, and because you have disabled dynamic mapping, the `products` items are not searchable.

Comment: Thanks Glenacota! This helped me fix it. In PHP I had an array of objects, filling an array with arrays gave me the right result! Didnt have to define nested or anything else weird on products (For people reading this in the future). Just have [ instead of { and you're all set. Glad I could give you the answer points!